# Change document root with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I made a router using a /public folder.

This folder contains my index.php that routes every route i need plus some css, js and stuff.

Using Wamp and a command line i can change the root folder to be /public

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

My job's done and i want to upload my newly created website to a server.

And... Yeah, i need to configure a .htaccess.

So, after some researches i found a "universal" solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

I needed to change the last line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]
```

Everything routes perfectly, the only problem is that css/js doesn't load. Looking at the superglobal $_SERVER it appears that

```
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "/home/routerphp"
```

does not contain my public folder.

I also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php
```

With the same result.

I'm kinda desperate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you just need to take a break and clear cache.
Everything is alright...